# Kafka server start is not working on command line

Tags: cmd, server, apache-kafka

If i try to run below command in order to start kafka server on CMD (Command Propmt)

```
C:\kafka_2.12-0.11.0.0\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat ..\..\config\server.properties
```

I get error as below

[image]

**Question:**

I just started to learn kafka so if i try to run above command i **can not start kafka server**.Where i miss exactly ? I still get error d**espite i delete log files**.How can i start kafka server ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Well the error text tells you that the file is used by another process. Do you have another kafka server running?

Beside that the file-path at the exception looks strange. I would try to use an absolute path:

`C:\kafka_2.12-0.11.0.0\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat C:\kafka_2.12-0.11.0.0\config\server.properties`

Answer (score 1):

See if the log.dirs configuration is wrong

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I restarted my machine thinking the file in contention will be cleared after restart. That didn't help. So, I cleared out the entire `tmp\kafka-logs` directory and restarted the kafka server and it worked fine.